# Javascript .match with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to get the information between this `url(` and this `)`.

There can be other things before and after that, like this:

```
background:url(images/backgrounds/bg_menu.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size:cover
```

I came up with this `/(?=u)(?=r)(?=l)(?=\().*(?=\))/` but it is not working.

I tried it after trying this: `/(?=url\().*(?=\))/` and I got what I wanted but the `url(` came with it.

Can anyone help me please? And explain the regex in details?

Comment: Did you try [`/url\((.*?)\)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/bE0tO2/1)? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you explain the regex for me please?

Comment: Or something like `/url\(([^)]*)\)/` - you don't need `?=` everywhere.

Comment: Given your stated criteria, I don't believe the currently accepted answer (by @stribizhev) is correct.

Comment: @Roy: It is correct. A capturing mechanism is the only way to go when you need both lookbehind and lookahead in a JS regex that does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: @stribizhev, my reading of the question is that that @Rafael didn't want the regex to match the initial `url(` text. I believe that the request was that only interior text should match.

Comment: The point is *to obtain the substring between the delimiters*. Checking a left-side context without matching it is impossible in JS.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue and your point. You are correct. The issue is that javascript doesn't have lookbehind, (i.e., `\b(?<=url\()[^)]*` won't work). So, as asked, the question is impossible to answer with a simple javascript regex. You might want to edit your answer to mention that lack of capability and that you have the closest possible simple regex solution. It's actually a solid, relevant point that searchers might miss (as I did). Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match something in-between delimiters, you may use lazy dot matching. If there are newline symbols inside, you will need to use lazy matching with `[\s\S]` or `[^]` in JS.

**See [*Lazy Quantifier Solution*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) at rexegg.com for more details about lazy dot  matching**.

Here is a sample regex:

```
/\burl\((.*?)\)/gi
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE0tO2/4)

Here, we match `url(` (as a whole word due to `\b` - a word boundary - that will make sure we only match `url(` and not `curl(`) with `url\(`, then match and capture what is between it and the closest `)` into group 1 with `(.*?)\)`.

Snippet:

```js
var re = /\burl\((.*?)\)/gi; 
var str = 'background:url(images/backgrounds/bg_menu.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size:cover';
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.write(m[1]); // With m[1], we access the text inside Group 1
}
```

However, you can also use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) solution:

```
/\burl\(([^)]+)\)/gi
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE0tO2/5)

Here, the `([^)]+)` matches and captures *1 or more characters other than `)`*. I think `+` quantifier is better as it will ignore all empty `url()`s.

Note that you do not have to escape `)` inside a character class, it will still be treated as a literal.

Comment: lazy matching gets you for a significantly higher number of backsteps / match failures though... a negated character class is probably the better option

Comment: Unless there are reasons to use lazy dot matching. Like the `)` may also appear inside the block. It would make more sense if the pattern was like `/url\((.*?)\)\s/gi` or `/url\((.*?)\);/gi`.

Comment: For more safety, I added the word boundary before `url(` to make sure we only match `url(`, not `curl(` or `hurl(`, etc.

Comment: Does this work with `.match()`? I tried `/\burl\((.*?)\)/` but it gave me back the hole string

Comment: No, it won't, because `match` with `/g` modifier does not return capture groups. See [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) reference: *If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. **Captured groups are not returned**.*

Answer (score 2):

there's a few working patterns. the simpler one to grasp being:

```
/url\(([^\)]*)\)/
```

first you literally match `url(`. then you create a capturing group `()` that matches everything that's not a literal closing paren (`[^\)]`) for any number of times in a row (`*`)

The one a little harder to explain is:

```
/url\((.*?)\)/
```

This also starts literally matching `url(`. Then you create a capturing group which matches everything, but lazily. This gets you in for catastrophic backtracking, because for every expansion you need to check the literal closing brace before advancing.

And a small snippet, based on the one in [stribizhev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770767/1803692)

```js
    var candidates = [/url\((.*?)\)/gi, /url\(([^\)]*)\)/gi]; 
    var str = 'background:url(images/backgrounds/bg_menu.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size:cover';
    
    for (var re of candidates) { 
        while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
            document.write(m[1]); // With m[1], we access the text inside Group 1
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    }
```